# Highcharts dynamically creating a primitives and setting position and size

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, renderer

Is it possible to place the rectangles over the lines?

One rectangle should have one or more lines in yAxis.
Rectangles should be added, moved and resized dynamically depends on data.

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yv84/rzrc1vnv/).

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="graph"></div>
   <button id="create">Create serier and add</button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```js
var chart;
$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 0;
var addRect = function (chart, x1, y1, x2, y2, r) {
    chart.renderer.rect(x1, y1, x2, y2, r)
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'red',
            fill: new Highcharts.Color('#ff0000').setOpacity(0.4).get(),
            zIndex: 10
        })
        .add();
}

function randomData(len, counter){
    var arr = [];
    i = 0;
    var rand;
    while (i<len) {
        if (!(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))) {
            arr.push(null);
        }
        //else {
            rand = Math.random()*5;
            i += rand;
            arr.push(counter);
            rand = Math.random()*5;
            i += rand;
            arr.push(counter);
            arr.push(null);
        //}
    }
    return arr;
}

var options = {
    chart:{
        renderTo:'graph',
        type:'line'
    },
    title:{
        text:null
    },
    xAxis: {
    },
    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            animation:false,
        }
    }
}

chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options,
        function (chart) {
            addRect(chart, 70, 120, 250, 120, 5);
            addRect(chart, 500, 120, 400, 120, 5);
            addRect(chart, 1200, 120, 150, 120, 5);
        });
var i = 1, s1,s2,s3,s4;

   function createChart(){
    s1 = chart.addSeries({
        data:randomData(20, counter++),
        name:'Line'+counter,
        lineWidth: 20},false);
    chart.redraw();
}

$('#create').click(function(){  createChart() });

})
```

Comment: Rectangle won't resize itself, you need to resize it. You can store rect element this way: `var myRect = chart.renderer.rect(x1, y1, x2, y2, r).attr({ ... }).add();`. Then later use `myRect.attr({ x: new_x, y: new_y, width: new_width, height: new_height });` to set new values for the rectangle.